# How to set an image as window background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I'm looking for a way to set a background image to my window. Something like the gnome-weather application:

[image]

The image is on the background and other components are on it.

That's my current window:

[image]

And I want a background more or less like this:

[image]
*Background edited with Gimp*

I downloaded the [gnome-weather](http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/sources/gnome-weather/3.14/) code to find out how it was done the background. I think it was done with CSS but I'm not sure, because JS is not my forte.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bg image of a window in a GTK3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158171/how-to-set-bg-image-of-a-window-in-a-gtk3-application) ?

Comment: Apparently yes http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=195278&hilit=GTK+with+CSS%3A+Background+images#p195278, but a python code would be better.
Well.... I'll see if I can get from this example in C.

Comment: Check this link: [GTK, Python and CSS are an awesome combo](http://wolfvollprecht.de/blog/gtk-python-and-css-are-an-awesome-combo/). You will find what you're looking for ;)

Comment: As a (less good) alternative, you could put a GtkImage in a GtkOverlay to display all other widgets above it.